# Spring Data JPA Find By List of Objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Given the following schema,

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String productName;

    private String category; 

    private String vendorName;

// Constructor, getters and setters
}
```

I would like to find all `products` that equals to any pair of `category` and `vendorName`
I have created a class for this

```
public class FilterRequest {
    private String vendorName;
    private String category;

// Constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Ideally the repo should have the following signature,

```
@Query(---QUERY---)
List<Product> findAllByFilterRequestList(List<FilterRequest> filterRequests);
```

Any idea how I should approach this? I am thinking of doing this one by one, but it will affect the performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) that uses predicate to filter out the products using the list of FilterRequest

**Service**

```
public List<Product> getAllProductsByFilterRequests(List<FilterRequest> filterRequests) {
    BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();
    filterRequests.forEach(
            filterRequest -> {
                    BooleanBuilder booleanBuilder2 = new BooleanBuilder();
                    booleanBuilder2.and(QProduct.product.category.eq(filterRequest.category));
                    booleanbuilder2.and(QProduct.product.vendorName.eq(filterRequest.vendorName));
                    booleanBuilder.or(booleanBuilder2);
            }
    );
    Predicate predicate = booleanBuilder.getValue();
    return (List<Product>) productRepository.findAll(predicate);
}
```

As you can see, `booleanBuilder` is the main predicate that aggregates the other predicate `booleanBuilder2`. `booleanBuilder2` is the one that checks if both vendorName and category values are equal with the product.

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Product> {}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. As mentioned above, I would like to match any of the (vendorName, category) pair

Comment: Sure, please try it and notify me if it solved your problem

Comment: so you mean list of FilterRequest? sorry i overlooked that

Comment: Are you saying that I should loop through the `List<FilterRequest>`?

Comment: I will edit my answer, i have another solution in mind

Comment: QProduct is auto-generated by QueryDsl during compile time. It is a copy of your entity `Product` which will then be used by QueryDsl to create predicates

Comment: Sorry I am new to QueryDSL. Trying to figure it out.  Anyway do you think there is a method to achieve the same goal without QueryDSL? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: One solution I have is simply fetching and iterate all the products, then perform filtering through manual stream/lamdba operation

Comment: This solution is not ideal as I will need to fetch the entire database before filtering. Is it possible to filter it at db level?

Comment: Uhm yes, the only way i know is through QueryDsl. You can give it a try, it's awesome and straightforward :)

Comment: Sure! You can give me a message if you need some help about it. Cheers